# Rails 3 command to embed text of my CSS stylesheets in head of my HTML

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku gives the [following advice](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/hypdf#performance-notes) for those using HyPDF to convert HTML to PDF format:

*`Place your styles and scripts within <style> and <script> tags instead of loading them using <link> tag.`*

Currently, I'm using the following:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "print", :media => "print, screen, projection"
```

What's the Rails 3.2 code to generate the `<style>` equivalent with embedded not linked CSS?

(That is with Rails automatically inserting all the CSS from `/app/assets/stylesheets/print.scss` into the HTML that it generates, rather than me manually copy-pasting all that CSS into a `content_tag` and then having to maintain the contents of that tag.)

Couldn't find anything in the API docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the following code right in the *head* section of your *application.html.erb* should work:

```
<style>
  <%= render :file => Rails.application.assets.find_asset('print') %>
</style>
```

Of course, if you're including stylesheets from several different views, you'll want to setup a yield in *application.html.erb* instead:

```
<style>
  <%= yield(:inline_style) %>
</style>
```

Then from each view:

```
<% content_for :inline_style %>
  <%= render :file => Rails.application.assets.find_asset('**stylesheet name**') %>
<% end %>
```

Or, if you still want to use the asset pipeline, see [How to inline css when using the rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386923/how-to-inline-css-when-using-the-rails-asset-pipeline)